# How do force or change my terminal to run python executable file in python 3 just by opening the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

My terminal is running python 2 so when I run my python file the program fails.

So basically I am new to programming and trying to create a small python script to help me auto create folders. I also want to give the script to colleges so that they can use it on their systems too.

I know that I can run my file in terminal by using "python3 myfile.py" and it will work, but that's too much off a mission to do for my colleges and as my colleges are not familiar with code or terminal for that matter, I wanted to create an executable file so that they just click to open type a few answers to the promoted question and boom folders created.

This is where I run into a problem, I have "#!/usr/bin/env python3" at the top of my file but when I run the script IDLE opens up and it just shows the code I have written but doesn't seem to run the actual script I wrote. Am I doing something wrong?

I also then though perhaps I could just use the terminal to run the file as it is now executable, so I go into terminal and enter "myfile.py" and the program runs but in python 2 so my script fails as it is in python3. So another question would be is there a way to code into my python file, when running this file make sure you use python3? as I would want this to work on all colleges system without them having to write out anything in terminal?

Sorry for the long explanation but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you are on windows you can just create a `.bat` file where you write: `python3 myfile.py` in it.
Both files have to be in the same directory.
If you want to have a `.exe` you can also use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).
You could also try  just `#!/usr/bin/python3` without `env`.
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57543952/edit).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am running MacOS, I have tried Platypus, I guess its the same as py2exe, it wraps your script into a .app file, but unfortunately it doesn't use input() so it won't work for me.I will give the #!/usr/bin/python3 a try and see if that works.